# laravel 5.3 having error to save directory name on the fly

Tags: laravel-5.3

i have tables artists, songs, and artist_song which is the pivot table

i want song to be uploaded and stored a new directory named after the artist that belongs that song . but iam getting this error

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$name
```

this is my store method on SongController.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'mp3'   => 'required',
            'artists' => 'required'

        ]);
        $song = new Song;
        $song->title = $request->title;
        $song->lyrics = $request->lyrics;
        $song->youtube_id = $request->youtube_id;
        $song->album_id = $request->album_id;
        $song->category_id = $request->category_id;

        if($request->hasFile('mp3')){
            $mp3 = $request->file('mp3');
            $trackname = $mp3->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = public_path('/uploads/songs/'.$song->artists()->name);
            if (!file_exists($path)){
                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            }


            $mp3->move($path, $trackname);
            $song->mp3 = $trackname;
        }
        $song->save();
        $song->artists()->sync($request->artists, false);
        return redirect()->route('song.index')->with('success', 'New song successfully upploaded');
    }
```

i cannot get name property of that artists..

so what is wrong with my code, and one more thing to help me with is this the correct way to do relation tables like this. i referenced a tutorial about tagging and i did the same

Comment: Try to remove the `()` from your relationship. change this: `$song->artists()->sync()` to this: `$song->artists->sync()`. let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Thanks bro @AfikDeri  for answering, but i didnot work, getting same error . cannot find name property of name property of artists